# unknown type name "pthread_barrier_t"

Tags: c, pthreads, windows-subsystem-for-linux, pthread-barriers

I am trying to parallelize an algorithm in C. I want to use `pthread_barrier_t` but my Ubuntu wsl can't find it for some reason. I have `pthread.h` included and I can use the rest of the pthread functions. `libthread.a` is installed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

/* Error occurs here */
pthread_barrier_t barrier;
```

Exact error is: *"identifier pthread_barrier_t is undefined"*

I saw elsewhere it could be the way I'm compiling.

Compiling as follows:

```
gcc -o test test.c -Wall -std=c99 -lpthread -lm
```

Also, VS Code can't identify the function.

Comment: Please post the contents of `gaus_elim.c` as well as the exact error you get.

Comment: I added some of the code up to the error

Comment: See if you can reproduce this with a minimal example. Create a C file with just two lines: `#include <pthread.h>` and `pthread_barrier_t barrier; int main(){}`, and see if you can get it to compile and run. If that fails too, then update your question to use it instead of your large amount of code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is your `-std=c99` option. Using strict C mode disables a bunch of stuff, including something that stops `pthread_barrier_t` from getting defined. If you use `-std=gnu99` instead, it should compile. (Tested on Ubuntu 16.04 on WSL).

Alternatively, add

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 600 /* Or higher */
```

or

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200112L /* Or higher */
```

*before* the first `#include` in your source. See [`man 7 feature_test_macros`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/feature_test_macros.7.html) for the acceptable values of these macros and more information.